# Error com.fasterxml.jackson Deploy .WAR Spring Boot in JBoss/Wildfly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss, wildfly

ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-22) Forwarding to error page from request [/api/method] due to exception [com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.hasLenient()Z]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.hasLenient()Z
at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.createContextual(JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.java:104)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:685)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:446)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** Create file named **jboss-deployment-structure.xml**
**-** Add the below block
**-** Copy file in location **WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
<deployment>
<exclusions>
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
<module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
<module name="org.slf4j" />
</exclusions>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

[IMG - Preview project Maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk55J.png)